# Breadcrumbs not appearing

Tags: 8, theming, breadcrumbs

I have a custom theme extending the bootstrap theme. In my theme there are no extra files except the .info.yml file. Everything else is inherited from bootstrap. I have also kept the regions in my custom theme, identical to the parent bootstrap theme.

For some reason none of the blocks including the breadcrumbs appear when I use my custom theme. I made sure to place those blocks from the block layout section inside those regions. But it's not showing. Weirdly, it's coming fine for the parent bootstrap theme and all of the core themes, but not my theme.

Breadcrumb visibility is also on in the theme settings page.

Any leads I can look into for checking where lies the problem?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I had to check the conditions applied to the block when it is placed inside a region.
For me, this was the case. The issue happened because of some default values stored from one of my custom condition plugins.